Openfile deprecated API after build app in VS Code
After build app get this message. I'm try change openfile version to last but again some.
Any idea how fix this?
Note: C:\Users\XXXXXX\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\open_file-3.3.2\android\src\main\java\com\crazecoder\openfile\OpenFilePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.


https://github.com/crazecoder/open_file/issues/282

@RichardHeap I don't see anything on above link only question which is similar as my....

You have to wait for the package owner to fix it. Or you can fix it and offer your update as a pull request. Package owner is aware - see open issue.
